# Where can i execute celery commands after deploying a django application on google app engine standard environment

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-celery, celerybeat

I am a django developer. One of my clients asked me to deploy the application on google app engine standard environment. I am new to this approach.
Redis is used as a task broker for celery in my application. As i have learnt there is no cli for GAE, so where can i run commands such as
`celery -A project worker --loglevel=info`
`celery -A project beat`
or am i making some kind of mistake here.